# Is there a way to handle exception thrown by class inheritance?

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I have a custom class which inherits another class. The parent class is throwing a System.NullReferenceException in a specific scenario. The parent class code cannot be edited at this point in time.

Very cut down version of my code-behind.

```
Public Class childClass
Inherits parentClass

'some additional variables declared...
Private oSite As New parentClass

'Following class variables, the functions are declared.

End Class
```

Is there a way I can handle a run-time error from MyBaseClass?

In fact I stripped out all functions, other variables to pinpoint the location of the error and it is the inheritance.

Comment: classes do not catch or throw anything. Functions throw and catch. Show exactly what code you are running that causes the NRE

Comment: I've edited the original code above, but essentially with everything stripped out and just the class inheriting the parent class, I get the dreaded Null Exception from the parent.

Comment: What's the call stack of the exception?  Is it throwing in the `ParentClass` constructor?  Have you tried to figure out why it's throwing (to see if there's a workaround)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Shadows` to wrap the problematic function in a try-catch:

```
Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim c As New Childclass
    Console.WriteLine(c.DodgyFunction) 'works
    Console.WriteLine("(press a key to continue)")
    Console.ReadKey()
    Dim p As New ParentClass
    Console.WriteLine(p.DodgyFunction) 'crashes
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub

  Public Class ParentClass
    Public Function DodgyFunction() As String
      Throw New InvalidOperationException("Exception in parent class")
    End Function
  End Class

  Public Class Childclass
    Inherits ParentClass
    Public Shadows Function DodgyFunction() As String
      Try
        Return MyBase.DodgyFunction()
      Catch ex As Exception
        Return "No exception!"
      End Try
    End Function
  End Class
End Module
```

Best practice is to fix the problem in the parent class, though.